# "Expected an arrow function after this type parameter declaration" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, flowtype

I got this error while running `yarn start`:

```sh
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.17
$ run-s build exec
$ babel src/ -d lib/
SyntaxError: .../src/App.js: Expected an arrow function after this type parameter declaration. (8:9)

   6 |
   7 | export default function App(): React$MixedElement {
>  8 |   return <p>Hello, React!</p>;
     |          ^
   9 | }
  10 |
```

Below are the configs:

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "flow": "flow",
    "start": "run-s build exec",
    "exec": "node lib/index.js",
    "build": "babel src/ -d lib/",
},
```

babel.config.json:

```json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-flow"],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-flow-enums"],
  "targets": {
    "esmodules": true
  }
}
```

App.js:

```js
// @flow

import "./App.css";

import React from "react";

export default function App(): React$MixedElement {
  return <p>Hello, React!</p>;
}
```

What the issue with my configs and react file?

Comment: You shuold use `@babel/preset-react` to make babel understand jsx syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a typo on `React.MixedElement`, replace the `$` by a `.`:

```
export default function App(): React.MixedElement {...}
```

Comment: I got the same error after switching to React.MixedElement.

Comment: @injoy Well have you tried to do as the error message says ? declaring your component as an arrow function : `const App: React.MixedElement = () => {...}`

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work. I think @banyudu pointed out the root cause: I need to use `@babel/preset-react` in babel.

Comment: @injoy Oh yes, did it works with this preset ?